# Include C++ library source in Netbeans project?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, include

Is there a "good" way to directly include a library's source in a Netbeans project?
When  I try to do it, I add the include directory in the Linker options and src in the source directories but I get a ton of "undefined reference" errors unless I add the folder into the project using right click>add existing items from folder.

Is there a better way to do this without having all the the code in the project ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

Select Tools->Libraries from the menu, create a new library there, then on right side click "***add Jar/folder***" to insert your folder.

Comment: You should add to your answer that you specify the source folder in the second tab. The third tab is for pointing to javadocs if available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't click on the button "New Library" though, it is disabled !